# Passing Location to other view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting location on my HomeViewController then I want to pass that to other NextViewController but it always returns nothing.

HomeViewController - Declaration

```
struct MyVariables {

static var  fetchedLat = String()
static var fetchedLong = String()
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var location: CLLocation!{
    didSet{
        lat = "\(location.coordinate.latitude)"
        long = "\(location.coordinate.longitude)"
    }
}

 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations  locations: [CLLocation])
{
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    MyVariables.fetchedLat = String("\(locValue.latitude)")
    MyVariables.fetchedLong = String("\(locValue.longitude)")
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    location = (locations ).last
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
    {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

NextViewController - ViewDidLoad

```
    MyVariables.fetchedLat = outputLat
    MyVariables.fetchedLong = outputLong
```

Please let me know if there is any better way so that I can access Lat & Long in all other ViewController in my App.

Comment: From where and how you passing location? Are you using segue ? if yes then where is `prepareForSegue` ?

Comment: I'm accessing it directly as I have declared Global Variable.

Comment: You should have `NextViewController's` object and property in that `NextViewController`. and you can set that value by that object!!

Comment: Sorry didn't get you. How ?

Comment: Simple, just go search in google with this line "passing data to another view controller ios swift" you will get lots of stuff there.

Comment: I have tried that.                      let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(“NextViewController") as? NextViewController
     next.outputLong =  MyVariables.fetchedLat     Still it returns nothing.

Comment: Don't use globals.  Pass the location in `prepareForSegue`.  Don't store latitude and longitude as separate strings.  Store a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`

Comment: Thanks. But I'm calling        performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_id", sender: self) in a Function where first I'm checking whether the user is already logged in or not. So In that function how to pass data ? I know how to do it in PrepareToSegue Function but I cannot use that over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define var passedData:CLLocationManger? globally in HomeViewController class

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        //let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        index = indexPath.row

        performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegue", sender: self)

    }
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)       
 {
        if segue.identifier == "yourSegue"
        {
        let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! NextViewController 
        destVC.locationData = passedData // both are of Type CLLocationManager
        }

    }
```

In NextViewController declare this globally in class:-

```
var locationData:CLLocationManager?
```

then access in NextViewController as

```
 locationData.location.coordinate.latitude

 locationData.location.coordinate.longitude
```

**Note:-** Instead of passing latitude and longitude, pass the CLLocationManager itself as you can access all properties of CLLocationManager i.e. Latitude, Longitude, Coordinate etc

Comment: I'm calling segue inside some other function with performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_id", sender: self) . Is there any other way to pass data via segue in that other function ?

Comment: yea define above method i.e. override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) anywhere within HomeViewController class but not inside any function. Consider prepareForSegue as a separate function

Comment: check now, i have defined performSegueWithIdentifier in tableView delegate method didSelect and using prepareForSegue as separate class method.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem and even got to learn how to do it in correct way.

Comment: It should be destVC.locationData = passedData Correct ?